# Struggling with 'synchronisation' between Session's in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest

I've a created `delete_entity` function which delete's entities and I've a function which tests this functions.

```
#__init__.py
engine = create_engine('sqlite://:memory')
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(engine))

# entity.py
def delete_entity(id, commit=False):
  """ Delete entity and return amount of amount of rows affected. """
  rows_affected = Session.query(Entity).filter(Entity.id == id).delete()
  if commit:
    Session.commit()
    # Marker @A

  return rows_affected

# test_entity.py
def test_delete_entity(Session):
   # ... Here I add 2 Entity objects. Database now contains 2 rows.

   assert delete_entity(1) == 1                 # Not committed, row stays in database.
   assert delete_entity(1, commmit=True)        # Row should be deleted 
   # marker @B 
   assert len(Session.query(Entity).all()) == 1
```

This test passes when I run the `test_delete_entity()` **alone**. But when I run this test together with other tests this test fails. It fails on `assert len(Session.query(Entity)).all()) == 1`. The query finds 2 rows, so it looks like the row hasn't been deleted. 
But, when I use the Python debugger (`pytest.set_trace()`) on @A and query for all Entity objects in the database I find 1 row. So the delete query was succesfull and one row has been deleted. But when I query for all Entity rows on @B I get 2 rows.

How can I 'synchronize' both Sessions, so my test will pass?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried but couldn't reproduce your issue. Here's my full script with the results:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Unicode
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)

Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


class Entity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_table'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(200))


Base.metadata.create_all()

e1 = Entity()
e1.name = 'first row'
e2 = Entity()
e2.name = 'second row'

Session.add_all([e1, e2])
Session.commit()

print len(Session.query(Entity).all())
# CORRECTLY prints 2

rows_affected = Session.query(Entity).filter(Entity.id == 1).delete()
print rows_affected
# CORRECTLY prints 1
Session.commit()

print len(Session.query(Entity).all())
# CORRECTLY prints 1
```

Since your script is not runnable, we can't find your issue.

Please provide a runnable script that shows the entire issue, like I did. The script must do all imports, insert the data, delete, and query in the end. Otherwise there's no way I can reproduce it here in my environment.